# Location of the "( visit meta )" link

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed

Can we please move that link to top right? Like this "log out | about | meta | faq" ? Please?

**Update:** Here is a screenshot

[image]

Comment: I agree. It's current placement makes it look almost more important than the title image.

Comment: Maybe put it under the logo, in the same line as the "Questions Tags..." line?

Comment: I agree with @Simon P Stevens. big time. lets make it like @Agnel suggested, otherwise it looks like it is part of the logo...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlikely, as we have a standard position for that link across the entire network.

And meta *is* really important.

edit: it turns out we needed that space, so this was indeed changed..

Comment: FAQ and About are also really important, so should they also move top left?

Comment: Well, you can get FAQ information from meta, and how many people click on the about link, anyways?

Comment: Can it be less ugly then? Looks fine in the beta SE themes, seems out of place on SF/SU.

Comment: @macha feel free to submit screenshots of what you think it should look like..

Comment: I found it quite jarring at first, but it's probably invisible to most users?

Comment: >  "we have a standard position for that link across the entire network"

Yes. The idea is to apply this change across the entire network.

Comment: @Agnel: EXACTLY! :)